# Change Libre Office language settings

Tags: 15.04

Since Ubuntu 14 LibreOffice and Thunderbird are using English.
Since Version 15, at least Thunderbird is in German again, but Office is inconvenient. I tried changing it with <kbd>Tools</kbd> > <kbd>Options</kbd> > <kbd>Settings</kbd> but I can only choose <kbd>English</kbd> or <kbd>English (USA)</kbd>

Comment: Hello! Welcome to AskUbuntu.com. This is an English speaking website. Please translate your question in English if you want to receive answers.

Comment: Have you tried installing the appropriate language packs, in case it's just the default that changed?

Comment: Es tut mir leid, aber dies ist eine rein englischsprachige Frage&Antwortseite. Da wir Benutzer aus der ganzen Welt haben, ist es uns leider nicht möglich, Fragen zu beantworten, die von den meisten nicht verstanden werden würden. Bitte übersetze deine Frage auf Englisch (auch https://translate.google.com reicht meist schon) oder suche dir eines der vielen deutschen Ubuntu-Foren aus um dort deine Frage zu stellen. Danke!

Answer (score 5):

Install the German language packs:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-help-de
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-l10n-de
```

and then change the language in LibreOffice again

[image]

Comment: for spell-checking add 
sudo apt-get install hunspell-de-de (https://askubuntu.com/questions/243065/cant-change-libreoffice-spell-check-language)

Answer (score 2):

It could be fixed like this.

Go to system settings on your computer, select **Language Support**, you will see this GUI:[image: GUI]

Then select **Install / Remove Languages**. After the window pops up, select **German**(not **Deutsch**)

Finally, select **Apply Changes**[image]

After the setting, go to **Libre Office**, and you will see the language **German**(Again, not**Deutsch**).
*(GUI Language should be translated)*